# Given $1<a<b<c$ prove $\log_a\log_ab+\log_b\log_bc+\log_c\log_ca>0.$

Tags: inequality, logarithms

> Given $1<a<b<c$ prove $$ \log_a\log_ab+\log_b\log_bc+\log_c\log_ca>0. $$

How to approach problems like this? I tried usual transformations but no help. I guess I have to use characteristic of logarithm function, but I'm not quite sure how to approach it.

Comment: $a,b,c$ are Reals? or precisely natural numbers?

Comment: Let $x,y,z$ be the natural logarithms of $a,b,c$. Express the inequality in these terms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}
& \log_{a}{\log_{a}{b}}+\log_{b}{\log_{b}{c}}+\log_{c}{\log_{c}{a}}>0 \\
& \Leftrightarrow \frac{\ln{\ln{b}}-\ln{\ln{a}}}{\ln{a}}+\frac{\ln{\ln{c}}-\ln{\ln{b}}}{\ln{b}}+\frac{\ln{\ln{a}}-\ln{\ln{c}}}{\ln{c}}>0 \\
& \Leftrightarrow \frac{\ln{\ln{b}}}{\ln{a}}+\frac{\ln{\ln{c}}}{\ln{b}}+\frac{\ln{\ln{a}}}{\ln{c}}>\frac{\ln{\ln{a}}}{\ln{a}}+\frac{\ln{\ln{b}}}{\ln{b}}+\frac{\ln{\ln{c}}}{\ln{c}}
\end{align}

The last inequality is true by rearrangement inequality since $\ln{\ln{c}}>\ln{\ln{b}}>\ln{\ln{a}}$ and $\frac{1}{\ln{a}}>\frac{1}{\ln{b}}>\frac{1}{\ln{c}}$ and the inequality is strict since the numbers are distinct.

Comment: Could you please explain how do you obtain $ \frac{ln(ln(b)) - ln(ln(a))}{ln a} $ from  $ \log_a(log_a(b))$ ? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Let us use the property of $log$.
We know that $\log_a b = \frac{\log_{10} b}{\log_{10}a}$.

If we apply that in your problem, we end up with 
$$\frac{\log_{10}b}{(\log_{10}a)^2}+\frac{\log_{10}c}{(\log_{10}b)^2}+\frac{\log_{10}a}{(\log_{10}c)^2} $$

Now we can able to see that the quantity is $>0$

Comment: But $\log_{a}{\log_{a}{b}}=\frac{\log{\log{b}}-\log{\log{a}}}{\log{a}}$

Comment: @IvanLoh im not sure how to proceed with that identity.